# Pattern matching for Android deep links

Tags: java, android, regex, uri, deep-linking

My app has to validate Uris like web links and deep links.

For web links like https://www.google.com I found this useful:

```
boolean validWebUrl =Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();
```

but it yields a negative value when used for deep links like appname://suitablestring

What is the equivalent of the above instruction for deep links?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the web url matching is based on checking strings like http:// https:// and so on.

So, for my purposes, I found that this workaround could be useful:

```
Uri url =Uri.parse(urlString);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent();
browserIntent.setData(url);
browserIntent.setAction(ACTION_VIEW);

try {
activity.startActivity(browserIntent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{

boolean validWebUrl =
        Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(urlString).matches();
if (!validWebUrl)
    {          
      openAlertDialog(activity,activity.getResources().getString(R.string.url_not_valid_dialog_title),activity.getResources().getString(R.string.url_not_valid_error_message));
    }
else {
      openAlertDialog(activity,activity.getResources().getString(R.string.activity_not_found_for_url_dialog_title),activity.getResources().getString(R.string.activity_not_found_for_url_message));
     }
}
```